# Meteor: how to retrieve "{{this}}-value" with a template event

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

Note: Whole code can be found here:

https://github.com/Julian-Th/crowducate-platform/tree/feature/courseEditRights

The issue: I can't retrieve the {{this}} value with an event. Console.log() is printing 0.

My HTML:

```
<!-- Modal to control who can collaborate on a course-->

<template name="modalAddCollaborators">
  <div id="modalAddCollaborators" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Manage Your Collaborators</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form" role="form">
          <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each  addedCollaborators}}
              {{#each canEditCourse}}
                 <li class="list-group-item js-listed-collaborator">{{this}}<a title="Remove Collaborator" id="remove-collaborator" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></li>
             {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" id="collaboratorName" placeholder="add a collaborator  ..." data-source="courses" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off">
            <button type="button" id="js-addCollaborator" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

My JS:

```
Template.modalAddCollaborators.rendered = function() {
    // initializes all typeahead instances
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
};

Template.modalAddCollaborators.courses = function(){
    return Courses.find().fetch().map(function(it){ return it.author; });
 //return users.find().fetch().map(function(it){ return it.username; });
};

Template.modalAddCollaborators.helpers({
    'addedCollaborators': function () {
        return Courses.find().fetch();
    }
});

Template.modalAddCollaborators.events({
    'click #js-addCollaborator' : function (event) {
        var collaboratorName = $('#collaboratorName').val(); // 
        Courses.update(
           {_id: this._id},
           {$addToSet: {canEditCourse: collaboratorName}}
        );
        $('#collaboratorName').val("");
    },
    'click #remove-collaborator': function (event) {
        var listedCollaborator = $('.js-listed-collaborator').val();
        console.log(listedCollaborator);
        Courses.update(
            {_id: this._id }, 
            {$pull: {canEditCourse: listedCollaborator}}
        );
    }
});
```

My MongoDB JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : "j7A3tFdFBn5ECQGwe",
    "title" : "Beatles",
    "coverImageId" : "RERiadyMx8j8C9QQi",
    "author" : "John",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "Paul"
    ],
    "published" : "true",
    "about" : "Testing the Course",
    "canEditCourse" : [ 
        "uo8SMdNroPGnxMoRg", 
        "FLhFJEczF4ak7CxqN", 
        "lkahdakjshdal", 
        "asödjaöslkdjalsöSA"
    ],
    "createdById" : "uo8SMdNroPGnxMoRg",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-12-28T16:30:34.714Z")
}
```

As seen in the JS-File, my final goal is to delete the clicked user from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of the `li` item in the child link click event, combine the use of **[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** and **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** (since you can't use **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** on list items):

```
'click #remove-collaborator': function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    var listedCollaborator = $(event.currentTarget).parent().text();
    console.log(listedCollaborator);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Template.parentData(0)));
    Courses.update(
        { 
            _id: Template.parentData(0)._id, /* or _id: Template.currentData()._id, */
            canEditCourse: listedCollaborator 
        }, 
        { $pull: { canEditCourse: listedCollaborator } }
    );
}
```

Notice you can use the current DOM element within the event bubbling phase through **[`event.currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)** to reference the element that kicked off the event. Since the element is the anchor tag, you get the `li` item as 
its **[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**, and subsequently get its value with **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**.

As for the update, use **[`Template.parentData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)** to get the parent `_id`. Specify a parameter of `0` in the method which denotes the current data context level to look.

For example, `Template.parentData(0)` is equivalent to `Template.currentData()`. `Template.parentData(2)` is equivalent to `{{../..}}` in a template.

Comment: Something very odd happens: console.log(listedCollaborator) prints some values while others are just empty (not even a 0). In my case, two of four are shown in the console - usually. However, all of them are still in the canEditCourse Array - so none of them are deleted. I added the JSON to the question. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: What does `console.log(event.target);` and `console.log($(event.target).parent());` print?

Comment: A screenshot is here: http://prntscr.com/9jmmkj  I once clicked on the icon itself (the first two logs) and then on the button (the last two logs).

Comment: $(event.currentTarget).parent().text(); fixed it. :) However, Courses.update doesn't delete the user.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Template.parentData(0)._id works :)  console.log(JSON.stringify(Template.parentData(1))) prints "Cannot read property  '_id' of null; 
And this._id is just "undefined". Do you know why? Anyway, I accepted your answer. You are my hero! Helping me out twice in a row.

Comment: @AmirRahbaran Nice one, had earlier on made a mistake; took the nesting of the `{{each}}` blocks as basis for the current data context level. You are right `Template.parentData(0)._id` should bring the desired context; I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you've attached your event handler to the `modalAddCollaborators` template `this` will be the data context of that template which is nothing.

Just setup a nested template at the level you want to catch the event.

Furthermore with this pattern you can identify the `_id` of the collaborator directly, it will be `this`. The course `_id` however comes from the context of the `parent` template. (I'm not sure whether the course level data context is 1 or 2 levels higher however).

**html:**

```
{{#each canEditCourse}}
  {{> nestedTemplate }}
{{/each}}

<template name="nestedTemplate">
  <li class="list-group-item js-listed-collaborator">
    {{this}}<a title="Remove Collaborator" id="remove-collaborator" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
  </li>
</template>
```

**js:**

```
Template.nestedTemplate.events({
  'click #remove-collaborator': function (event) {
    Courses.update({_id: Template.parentData()._id },{$pull: {canEditCourse: this}});
  }
});
```

Comment: The result ist the same: 0 :(

Comment: Oh I see, `canEditCourse` is an array of strings, not objects. There is no `this._id` in your data context there is only `this` (with no keys). I'll change the code.

Comment: Now I get this: meteor.js:864: Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/courses/update' Error: documentMatches needs a document(…) Error: documentMatches needs a document